# Is there an equivalent & expression in C for >> 31

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, crc32

I am trying to understand a CRC-32 algorithm. Is there an equivalent expression for:

```
y = (X >> 31) ^ (data >> 7);
```

using `&`, something like

```
y = (x & 0x8000) ^ (data & 0x800)
```

Comment: Why do you need *equivalent expression* ? It's like a question: Is there a equivalent operator for +

Comment: no, only `<<` and `>>` shift the bit positions, other bitwise operators apply their logic bitwisely (bit-by-bit) at that bit position, so you can't change this bit by some bit at another position

Comment: if `X` is `uint32` then `X >> 31` is equivalent to `!!(x & 0x80000000)`

Comment: There's no need to do the xor 1 bit at a time. For a MSB / left shift CRC, you can use | crc = crc ^ (((uint32_t)data)<<24); | and for a LSB / right shift CRC, you can use | crc = crc ^ ((uint32_t)data); | . After the xor, then cycle the CRC 8 times.

Comment: You can use `/` instead of `>>`, but not `&`.  Unless you have a lot of if statements.  If `x` is a 32-bit type or you are certain that all the bits above the 32nd are zero, then `x >> 31` is equivalent to `x & 31 ? 1 : 0`.  However the `>>` is faster.

Answer (score 3):

Well it depends on your calculations but in bit operations each operator has its own motive to do things. Same answer can be obtained by different operations but that doesn't mean that operator to equivalent to each other. Each operator has different motive to achieve.

```
bit a   bit b   a & b (a AND b)     a | b (a OR b)   a ^ b (a XOR b)
  0       0          0                0                   0
  0       1          0                1                   1
  1       0          0                1                   1
  1       1          1                1                   0
```

The purpose of << and >> is to shit bits/drop bits from calculations

## Right Shift

The symbol of right shift operator is >>. For its operation, it requires two operands. It shifts each bit in its left operand to the right. The number following the operator decides the number of places the bits are shifted (i.e. the right operand). Thus by doing ch >> 3 all the bits will be shifted to the right by three places and so on.

```
i = 14; // Bit pattern 1110
j = i >> 1; // bit pattern shifted 1 thus we get 111 = 7 = 14/2
```

## Left shift

The symbol of left shift operator is <<. It shifts each bit in its left-hand operand to the left by the number of positions indicated by the right-hand operand. It works opposite to that of right shift operator. Thus by doing ch << 1 in the above example we have 11001010. Blank spaces generated are filled up by zeroes as above.

Left shift can be used to multiply an integer in multiples of 2 as in:

```
 int i = 4; /* bit pattern equivalent is 100 */
 int j = i << 2; /* makes it 10000, original number by 4 i.e. 16 */
```